# ruby rest-client ipv6 request failure with Apache 2.2.31

Tags: ruby, apache, https, ipv6, rest-client

I've been stuck with this for about two days...

I use ruby(version 2.3.3p222) gem rest-client(v2.0.0) to send a GET request with a ipv6 url to the server (Apache/2.2.31):

```
url =  'https://[fd36:4928:8040:dc10:0000:0000:0000:0160]:8080/resources/1'
resource = RestClient::Resource.new(url, :ssl_version => 'TLSv1', :verify_ssl => false, :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic cm9vdDAbCdEfwYXNzMSE='})
```

resource.get

I got a 400 bad response and the body says:"Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request"

However I can use curl command with the same parameters and get the right response, so I suspect maybe it's something wrong with the header of my rest-client request.

PS: I also tested with adding the 'host'

```
header: {'Authorization' =>  'Basic cm9vdDAbCdEfwYXNzMSE=', 'host' => '[fd36:4928:8040:dc10:0000:0000:0000:0160]:8080' }
```

It still failed with the same bad response.

I just noticed the appache error for this  request, it says:
**"httpd[29124]: [error] Hostname fd36:4928:8040:dc10:0000:0000:0000:0160 provided via SNI and hostname fd36:4928:8040:dc10:0000:0000:0000 provided via HTTP are different
"**

Comment: Can you show your curl command?

Comment: @Joe curl --user admin:password -k https://[fd36:4928:8040:dc10:0000:0000:0000:0160]:8080/resources/1

Comment: Take the "host" header back out, and fix the auth header as shown below, and try again - any errors in the apache log?

Comment: @Joe seems similar to this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=500981

Comment: There's a typo in the question code `header:` rather than `headers:`. Was that also what you tested with? When I try passing an explicit Host header I get an exception raised by Net::HTTP, which seems to indicate a Ruby bug. `URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected host component): [`

Answer (score 0):

The curl command you supplied would translate `--user admin:password` into the following header:

```
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

However, you're sending

```
Basic: cm9vdDAbCdEfwYXNzMSE=
```

which is not the same thing... so the server is probably complaining about not getting the correct auth...

Comment: sorry for the typo, it was 'Authorization' =>  'Basic cm9vdDAbCdEfwYXNzMSE=' and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be either a bug in rest-client or a regression in Ruby Net::HTTP.

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/583

What version of Ruby are you using? Have you tried using Ruby 2.1 to see if it works there?

**EDIT:**

This is [Ruby Bug #12642](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12642). The `Host` header for an IPv6 address is sent with no enclosing `[` `]`.

Ruby in 2.1.6 - 2.1.10 doesn't have the bug, but versions >= 2.2.0 are affected.

And worse still, there's a bug with setting an explicit IPv6 Host header so you get an exception `URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected host component): [`

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32], seems it does include the brackets. (I checked this by adding "p req.to_hash" at the end of ruby lib /net/http.rb#begin_transport). My case is more like this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=500981. Ruby uses row ip as SNI host (which shouldn't) and Apache mistakenly truncates the ipv6 hostname...

Comment: So I haven't looked into the SNI stuff, but I'm fairly confident the linked bug is affecting you. `begin_transport` is called before `Net::HTTPGenericRequest#exec`, which is where the correct behavior is present in Ruby 2.1 but was removed by https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/70a2eb63. Because the Host header does not contain brackets, Apache is treating the final :0160 as a port rather than as part of the IP address. I'd suggest looking at the headers with a netcat server or similar.

Comment: you are right after a double check, brackets are missing! And after check with the commit link,  this line: if host = self['host']
host.sub!(/:.*/s, ''.freeze) is apparently buggy for ipv6 address. Wow, ruby guys should notice this...

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and googling for another day, this problem seems to be clear:

From a similar bug report to chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=500981, "SNI is only hostnames, and should never contain IPs.". However ruby does use ip as hostname (in this case rest-client is nothing to blame since it just delegate everything down to ruby lib). You can find evidence in Net::HTTP#connect (around line 922):

```
      # Server Name Indication (SNI) RFC 3546
      s.hostname = @address if s.respond_to? :hostname=
```

Just comment out the last line it will work (to workaround this you have to do a monkey patch). Additionally, as pointed out by @alberge, host header does not contain brackets, the final request host header is like this: "FD36:4928:8040:DC10::162", no "[ ]" around.

Also on Apache side, it does something wrong since it just strips off everything from the last colon to get the host name without any extra check-  this still exists in version 2.4.10, not sure if it is fixed or not.